# How to get data from a global variable on Vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

Simple question, I've read some similar questions but non of them help me to solve this.so basically I'm using a [Flatpickr](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr) component

what I need is to update a variable everytime that the component is triggered,
hopefully that component has an [onchange method](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/events/)

main.js

```
data() {
 return {
  VehicleID: '',
   Id: '',
   Postcode: 'E1',
   StartDate: '',
   ReturnDate: '',

   StartDateConfig: {
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "d M Y H:i",
    defaultDate: (new Date()).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7),
    minDate: (new Date()).setDate(new Date().getDate() + 2),

    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      UpdateDetails(Id,'from', dateStr); // need to pass the id
   },
  }
 }
}
.....

function UpdateDetails(Id, type, value) {
}
```

I need to send the id or either the object to get the id on my UpdateDetails method

Comment: Use an event bus, or define the variable in a separate module, and import that into wherever you need it (singleton pattern), or declare the variable outside the scope and bind it to the `window` instance, or define it as an object and set the vue data to that object. Lots of ways, but I'd recommend an event bus.